# PKG_CHECK_MODULES syntax error near luajit

Tags: c, gnu, autotools, autoconf, automake

I'm new to GNU autotools.In my project when i try `./configure` it generates following error :

```
./configure: line 9852: syntax error near unexpected token `luajit,'
./configure: line 9852: `    PKG_CHECK_MODULES(luajit, luajit,LLUAJIT="yes",LLUAJIT="no")'
```

In **Configure.in** :

```
 PKG_CHECK_MODULES(luajit, luajit,LLUAJIT="yes",LLUAJIT="no")
    if test "x$LLUAJIT" = "xyes"; then
        CONFIGFLAGS="$CONFIGFLAGS -DHAVE_LIBLUAJIT"
        LUA_CFLAGS="$luajit_CFLAGS"
        LUA_LIBS="$luajit_LIBS"
        AC_SUBST(LUA_CFLAGS)
        AC_SUBST(LUA_LIBS)
        if test "x$macos" != "xno"; then
            LDFLAGS="${LDFLAGS} -pagezero_size 10000 -image_base 100000000"
        fi

    else
        echo
        echo "   ERROR!  LuaJIT library not found. For better performance, go get it from"
        echo "   http://www.luajit.org/."
        AC_MSG_ERROR("Fatal!")
    fi
```

It seems autoconf(maybe) is unable to find `PKG_CHECK_MODULES` macro. I searched the Internet for solution and found that it is because `libtool` is not installed.I re-installed `libtool` but error remains same.

Hope Someone recognizes the problem and has quick solution for it.Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `PKG_CHECK_MODULES` macro is defined in the `pkg.m4` file and `pkg.m4` is part of pkgconfig package. So in order to use this macro, make sure pkgconfig is be installed on your system, and pkg.m4 is in the right place, on most system it is at:

```
/usr/share/aclocal/pkg.m4
```

In you configure script, enable libtool and add macro dir:

```
LT_INIT
AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIRS([m4])
```

Comment: please post your entire configure.ac.

Comment: There are two configs missing in your configure script, see updated answer.

Comment: On Ubuntu/Debian systems it's got a dash in the package name: `pkg-config`

Answer (score 14):

For those who end up here searching the solution , following worked for me :

[PKG_CHECK_MODULES breaking in solaris](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6758442/pkg-check-modules-breaking-in-solaris?rq=1)

The `PKG_CHECK_MODULES` macro doesn't seem to be expanded properly. When you installed `pkg-config`, did it install `pkg.m4` (in somewhere like `/usr/share/aclocal`)? If so, try running `aclocal` again (maybe with `-I m4`, if you've got custom `m4` code in the `m4` subdirectory) and then run `autoconf`.

If that doesn't work and `pkg.m4` was installed, try running `autoreconf -f` (and maybe `autoreconf -i -f`).

If that doesn't work, you'll need to copy `pkg.m4` to a directory for your package. Usually this is the `m4` subdirectory. Set `ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS = -I m4` (or `ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS = -I m4 --install`) in `Makefile.am` (if you're using `automake`), and `AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR([m4])` in `configure.ac`. Then run `aclocal -I m4` and `autoconf` and `./configure`.

Comment: Just wanted to add: this may happen if a "autogen.sh" is not included (which means after a fresh checkout there already is a ./configure script). The autogen script is usually just a "autoreconf -fiv" or whatever. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I added the conf file before installing the libtool, so you need to run again `autoreconf -i -f` after installing the libtool